# Dynamically add to thymeleaf list?

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am rendering a list of objects using thymeleaf into dynamically numbered rows.  I am using th:field for input objects.  At runtime, if my list has two elements, my HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="fieldRows">
  <div class="row" id="fieldRow_0">
    <input type="text" id="customFieldDefinitions0.name" name="customFieldDefinitions[0].name"/>
    <input type="text" id="customFieldDefinitions0.type" name="customFieldDefinitions[0].type"/>
  </div>
    <div class="row" id="fieldRow_1">
    <input type="text" id="customFieldDefinitions1.name" name="customFieldDefinitions[1].name"/>
    <input type="text" id="customFieldDefinitions1.type" name="customFieldDefinitions[1].type"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using JQuery, I have an "Add" button that grabs the last entry in fieldRows, clones it, and then appends it; this allows me to add rows to the list.  HOWEVER, all of the fields have the same name / id values as the bottom-most row, necessitating I manually replace them with updated values.  Is there a better / easier way to do this, i.e. something I can name the additional row inputs so that thymeleaf sees them as list additions?

Comment: By the time you are using jQuery and JavaScript, there is no Thymeleaf - only HTML. There is nothing for Thymeleaf to "see". For this reason, I don't think this is a Thymeleaf question. You are going to have to parse _something_ from the HTML to create `id="fieldRow_2"` (for row 3). Even if you added a Thymeleaf generated attribute such as `data-id="1"` (for row 2) that wouldn't save you much JavaScript code. If I've misunderstood what you mean, can you clarify?

Comment: Another perspective: Not everything needs an ID - so you could save some coding by not having IDs, if they are never referenced (but I guess the names are needed, especially if the data is in a form).